# Does HighPerformanceCache require some special actions for correct shutdown?

Tags: neo4j

In my application, I use the following configs (relevant part):

```
"org.neo4j.server.database.mode" : "HA",
"neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory" : "20M",                                      "neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory" : "40M",                                      "neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory" : "60M",
"neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory" : "40M",
"neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory" : "40M",
"cache_type" : "hpc",
"cache.memory_ratio" : "60.0"
```

With Xmx set to 7G on a machine with 16GB of RAM.
The problem is that during spme of our tests we are repeatedly launching and closing neo4j-based application and it seems that even after I call `db.shutdown()`, the caches still aren't purged or deallocated or whatever it is called.
Using Eclipse MAT I found out this:

```
2 instances of "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.HighPerformanceCache",
loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x6ca4755a8"
occupy 137,442,768 (13.03%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.HighPerformanceCache @
     0x708c74ed0 - 68,721,384 (6.51%) bytes.
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.HighPerformanceCache @
     0x708d7e570 - 68,721,384 (6.51%) bytes.
```

In our tests, we are properly closing each application that uses neo4j (I re-checked it and I'm totally sure), and after approximately 20 runs those `HaCaches` instances take up all the available heap and crash JVM.

If that's important, the JVM isn't actually being shutdown between consecutive test runs, so I guess if caches are freed only upon JVM shutdown, my issue has something to do with this fact?

Comment: Can you see the path too root for the instances of the HPC ?

Comment: Do you also release the db reference to be gc'ed ?

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick test but couldn't reproduce your findings:

```
public class HPCLeakTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("target/hpc-test").setConfig("cache_type", "hpc").newGraphDatabase();
            try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
                Node n = db.createNode();
                db.getNodeById(n.getId());
                tx.success();
            }
            db.shutdown();
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("done, run " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Done, awaiting input");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: It was fixed after switch to 2.2. I guess it had something to do with this PR: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4288.